# Help with 'Invert Overview' QGIS v1.9

Tags: qgis

I'm using the Atlas functionality in QGIS 1.9 to create a set of maps. So far, so good. But I want to be able to create a smaller map in the margin that acts as a map index.

I've seen a blog post by Underdark which indicates that the Invert Overview may be the option that helps with this. I haven't been able to find any more information about this toggle and how to use it.

Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 1):

So I've found that I needed to set my Overview Frame to my Map 0. That has helped to get the focus of the map tile that I want to highlight.

But how do I get that to change with the grid over my map?

Comment: It will update when Altas moves though your coverage layer.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I'll keep playing around with it. It's not working as I had hoped so I've probably done something 'unexpected'.

Comment: So I'm still playing around with this and not getting any further. Where I'm stuck is in being able to get that overview map to 'move' with the different pages of the atlas.  So, for instance, when my main map is map 5 I want the overview map to show that maps 1,2and 3 are above, 7 8 and 9 are below, 4 is to the left and 6 to the right. Then when my main map is map 8, I want to see that 4,5 and 6 are above, 10,11 and 12 below and 7 and 9 to the right and left respectively.

Comment: I'm not sure that is supported yet because the altas can only work on a single map frame.  Planned for 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tick the Invert Overview checkbox

[image]

Comment: That sounds so obvious :)

Comment: but it doesn't produce the result, for me, that Underdark's image shows. So I'm thinking that I'm missing something.